# How to change font in drawString of array in java?

Tags: java, fonts, applet

I am having problem of changing the font in drawstring that uses array string inside paint method. i am trying to change the font to bold and this is my code-

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
 {//PRINTING OF QUESTIONS
 k=0;
 for(i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
 Font myFont = new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN,12);
que[x[i]].setFont(myFont);

 g.drawString((i+1)+" ."+que[x[i]],50,50+k);
 k=k+150;
}
 }
```

The above code is showing this error-

```
Cannot find Symbol.
que[x[i]].setFont(myFont);
```

but while adding 'myFont' to add() of any array it is changing the font.

Comment: This is one of the stranger methods I've seen. How does this compile? Unless `i` and `k` are class level variables for some reason?

Comment: I suggest you post the code initializing `x`, or some additional information about `x`. Might be a casting issue. Or you trying to apply a `Font` to a `String`, which would not work.

Comment: but adding font to string should work? don't you think so. @mena

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer:-

```
 g.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD, 12));
```